# How to run only one timer in web

Tags: javascript, html, angular, timer, setinterval

I want to increment 1 second to time in each second. I need to use `localStorage` for another purpose... 
So, I put a `setInterval` and increment each second to the `localStorage`

But the issue is that if I open the same page in two tabs, seconds get incremented by 2 times.

I want to run only one increment at a time. How can I do it...

Here is what I have tried so far

This is the code I have to increment time

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {
localStorage.setItem('currentTime',String(currentTime));
});
```

** Note:**

I understand the point that I can just have a local variable and display in UI, But I want to store in `localStorage` for another purpose.

To replace setInterval, I am ready to change `Observable.interval` also, like

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
  Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
    localStorage.setItem('currentTime',String(currentTime));
  });
```

But it won't do anything to check whether any existing incrementer is running or not. How can I do this

Comment: What is `currentTime` here? read from `localStorage`?

Comment: Current Time is local time in microseconds, and thats what i am storing in local storage

Comment: If you want to have two "currentTime", you need two "currentTime" :). At init of your application create a "unique id" (you can use new Date().getTime) save in a variable. Then you can save in localStore.setItem(your_uniqueID,currentTime) and localStore.getItem(your_uniqeID). Don't forget in onDestroy remove the localStore(your_uniqueID)

Comment: Thnks, i am trying to establish your solution in answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage to not save the time into localstorage in case the difference betwen the last saved time and the new time to save is not equals to your interval period:

```js
this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var lastTime = localStorage.getItem('currentTime');
    if (lastTime) {
        var lastTimeTimestamp = new Date(lastTime).getTime();
        var currentTimeTimestamp = currentTime.getTime();
        if (currentTimeTimestamp - lastTimeTimestamp >= 1000) {
            localStorage.setItem('currentTime',String(currentTime));
        }
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('currentTime',String(currentTime));
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: i already have my time in microseconds.. So can i do something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/612zfrd4/